# HSQLDB never closes DB connection

Tags: java, database-connection, hsqldb, database-connectivity

I'm playing with this kind of database, and I've tried to close the HSQLDB connection after I used it, but it's still opened at the end.

Code:

```
//----This methods are in a specific connection class file
    public static Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection getConnection(){       
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("PathToMyPropertiesFile");
            prop.load(input);
            //The properties constants are correctly checked
            Class.forName(prop.getProperty("DRIVER_HSQLDB"));
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("CONN_HSQLDB"));
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            LOG.log(null,"Error: "+e);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(null,"FILE ERROR: "+ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.log(null,"CLOSE ERROR: "+e);
                }
            }
        }   
        return conn;
    }
public static boolean stopConn() {
        try {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                System.err.println("\nCLOSE CONN\n"+conn);
                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

//========= the other class file with the methods to use the conneciton
public static boolean insertUser(String uName, String uEmail){
        Connection con;
        con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            String consulta = "insert into USERS (\"NICK\",\"EMAIL\") VALUES(?,?);";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);

            System.err.println(ps);
            ps.setString(1,uName);
            ps.setString(2,uEmail);
            System.err.println("\nASSIGNATION\n"+ps);

            if(ps.executeUpdate() == 1) {
                System.err.println("\nTRUE\n");
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                System.err.println("\nFINALLY\n"+ps);
                if(ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                    System.err.println("\nCLOSE PS\n"+ps);
                }
                if(con != null) {
                    con.close();
                    System.err.println("\nCLOSE CON\n"+con);
                    if(ConnectionDB.stopConn()) {
                        System.err.println("\nALL IS OK\n"+ConnectionDB.conn);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.err.println("\nMEEEEKKKK!!!\n"+ConnectionDB.conn);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The console give me this results, and I don't know why never the connection is closed because I tried to close it twice. If someone has an idea please tell me.

> org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@4501280b[sql=[insert into USERS ("NICK","EMAIL") VALUES(?,?);], parameters=[[null], [null]]]
>
> ASSIGNATION
>   org.hsqThis is my cldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@4501280b[sql=[insert into USERS ("NICK","EMAIL") VALUES(?,?);], parameters=[[extra], [extra@mail.com]]]
>
> TRUE
>
> FINALLY
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@4501280b[sql=[insert into USERS ("NICK","EMAIL") VALUES(?,?);], parameters=[[extra], [extra@mail.com]]]
>
> CLOSE PS
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@4501280b[closed]
>
> CLOSE CON
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@3e5b87f5
>
> CLOSE CONN
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@3e5b87f5
>
> ALL IS OK
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@3e5b87f5

Comment: I checked the 1.8 API [link](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html#isClosed()), and I added a `con.isClosed();`. The code give me a `true`value (connection closed properly), but `.lck` file is not removed and the `con` value in not deleted either (still having the token value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing a JDBC connections does not close an in-process database. This allows you to open and close different connections during the runtime of your application.

You need to execute a JDBC Statement to shutdown the database. The SQL statement to execute is "SHUTDOWN".

It is possible to add a connection property "shutdown=true" to the JDBC connection URL to force a quick shutdown when the last connection to the in-process database is closed. But this is mainly useful for readonly or test databases. A full SHUTDOWN allows the database to open quickly the next time a connection is made.

See the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess

Comment: Thanks for the help. I saw the guide to shutdown the database [http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_closing_db], and I add to my `stopConn()` code this: `conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:PATH_TO_MY_DB;shutdown=true","sa","");`
And after this line I print `conn` varaible, and still giving me a connection value: `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@1b90ffd0`. If I am forcing a data base shutdown, the connection should be `null/none/nothing`, no?

Comment: No. A closed connection is still not null. It is closed. You can check that is closed with a JDBC call.